# LOOP not working in R

Tags: r

This doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

```
look_up  <- data.frame(flat=c("160","130"),
                   street=c("stamford%20street", "doddington%20grove"),
                   city = c("London", "London"),
                   postcode = c("SE1%20", "se17%20"))

new <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(look_up)){
  new <- rbind(new,look_up$flat[i])
}
```

Grateful if someone could tell me why please!  My result should be a data frame with one column called 'flat' and the values of 160 and 130 on each row. Once I understand this I can move onto the real thing I'm trying to do!

Comment: You loop doesn't work as expected because `look_up$flat` is a factor and not a character. Use `as.character` to transform it or the `stringsAsFactors` parameter when creating the data.frame.

Comment: Why is a vector as a result not sufficient?

Comment: PS: Thank you Roland.

Comment: Have included 'as.character' and also 'stringsAsFactors' in the above example but no joy still. I don't understand why it doesn't create a new dataframe with my result. As noted, I realise there are quicker ways to get to the same result, but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work as I'll need to do similar things for other projects.

Comment: I have rolled-back your last change to preserve the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a loop:

```
look_up[,"flat",drop=FALSE]
```

As mentioned, the problem with your loop is automatic conversion to factors. You can put `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`in front of your script to avoid that.

However, it's almost certain that you are approaching your actual problem in the wrong way. You should probably ask a new question, where you tell us what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Hi all,Thanks for the replies. The thing is that I do need to use a LOOP as after this I am going to construct URLs to send off to an API. I realise that there are quicker ways to get the result I'm after above, but I'd like to understand why what I have wrote doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the `stringsAsFactors` argument of [`data.frame`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/data.frame.html).

```
look_up  <- data.frame(flat=c("160","130"),
                   street=c("stamford%20street", "doddington%20grove"),
                   city = c("London", "London"),
                   postcode = c("SE1%20", "se17%20"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
look_up[, "flat", drop = FALSE ]
```

Comment: Hi all,Thanks for the replies. The thing is that I do need to use a LOOP as after this I am going to construct URLs to send off to an API. I realise that there are quicker ways to get the result I'm after above, but I'd like to understand why what I have wrote doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like:

```
> look_up  <- data.frame(flat=c("160","130"),
+                        street=c("stamford%20street", "doddington%20grove"),
+                        city = c("London", "London"),
+                        postcode = c("SE1%20", "se17%20"))
> 
> new <- look_up[,1,drop=FALSE]
> new
  flat
1  160
2  130
> class(new)
[1] "data.frame"
```

This shows your final desired output is a dataframe with 160 and 130 on columns. 
If you don't include `drop=FALSE` here, then your final output will be a factor.
Hope this helps.